# Generating joins from tables in entities in Zend Framework 2 + Doctrine 2

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, doctrine-odm

using the following command I can generate classes from tables:

```
./vendor/doctrine/doctrine-module/bin/doctrine-module orm:convert-mapping --namespace="Application\\Entity\\" --force --from-database annotation ./module/Application/src
```

Using this command, I can generate getters/setters:

```
./vendor/doctrine/doctrine-module//bin/doctrine-module orm:generate-entities ./module/Application/src/ --generate-annotations=true
```

Is it possible to generate the joins based on foreign keys setup in the database?

Thanks.